# how to deploy 2.1 entity bean in Wildfly8.1.0

Tags: jboss

when i had deployed an entity bean [which had worked in jboss7.1.1] it is showing

2014-07-19 17:13:51,920 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jacorb] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS016330: CORBA ORB Service started
2014-07-19 17:13:52,246 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."simpCmp.jar".PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."simpCmp.jar".PARSE: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "simpCmp.jar"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.8.0_11]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS014588: CMP Entity Beans are not supported
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.entity.EntityBeanComponentDescriptionFactory.processEntityBeanMetaData(EntityBeanComponentDescriptionFactory.java:65)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.entity.EntityBeanComponentDescriptionFactory.processBeanMetaData(EntityBeanComponentDescriptionFactory.java:57)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.processDeploymentDescriptor(AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:143)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.deploy(AbstractDeploymentUnitProcessor.java:84)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.1.0.Final.jar:8.1.0.Final]
    ... 5 more